# PHP count row returns error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm using the following to count the number of rows in my table:

```
$book_count = query("SELECT status FROM scifi_book WHERE read = $uid");
(count($book_count));
echo $book_count;
```

and i get the following error:

```
Notice:  Array to string conversion on line 167
```

(which is the line `echo $book_count;`)

FIY, the `query` function is defined and works fine. Never had any issues to insert, select, update and delete.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What does `query()` return? And where does `$follower_count` in your question come from?

Comment: @andrewsi this was a mistake when i copy pasted my code.Just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$book_count = query("SELECT status FROM scifi_book WHERE read = $uid");
echo count($book_count);
```

Also, you need to use `print_r($book_count)` since your `$book_count` is not a string.

Comment: I don't understand the last statement (use `print_r` because `$book_count` is not a string). May you elaborate, please?

Comment: Ah, got it. He also echoes the variable content; didn't see that before.

Comment: @Racso: you use echo for strings, `$book_count` is an array object returning query results. To echo array use `print_r`

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm ! I'll be able to accept your answer in 6 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: if you only use that query for getting the count, this may be a bit better:

```
$book_count = query("SELECT count(*) FROM scifi_book WHERE read = $uid");
```

Answer (score 1):

your query function seems to return an array, not a string. Instead of `echo $follower_count` use `print_r($follower_count)` to see what's inside the query response.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing that error is because you are `echo`ing `Array` which is the returned by your `query` function.  `echo` construct only works on strings, please see the documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php.

Had you used `print_r` or `var_dump` then you wouldn't have seen that error.  So as @A.S. Roma and Nathaniel Granor suggest use `print_r`

Answer (score 1):

```
$book_count = query("SELECT status FROM scifi_book WHERE read =".$uid);
(count($book_count));
echo $book_count;
```